# Capybara Poltergeist IOError: closed stream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, poltergeist

I am using Capybara for web page scraping. I noticed a problem in which afterwards Poltergeist hangs around in the memory eating system resources. The Poltergeist Github page notes that there is a memory leak issue with Capybara (https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist) and they recommend calling

```
session.driver.quit
```

That fixes the memory issue for me, but when I want to use Capybara again later I receive the error message:

```
IOError: closed stream
```

I believe just refreshing the Capybara session will fix this but can't find a public method that allows me to restart with a brand new session.

1) Is there a method that will fix my issue?

2) Is resetting the session the best way of reopening the stream?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution that worked best was to initiate a new Capybara session like this:

```
session = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist, Rails.application)
session.visit(...)
session.driver.quit
```

For my program I encapsulated it in a WebScraper module like this:

```
module WebScraper
  attr_accessor :session

  delegate :visit, :save_screenshot, to: :session

  def start_session
    @session ||= Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist, Rails.application)
  end

  def end_session
    @session.driver.quit
    @session = nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your client memory is overloading with the memory leak so restarting the browser can solve the problem. You can check the client info by `session.driver.browser.client`. You can restart your browser by `session.driver.browser.restart` then it opens a browser with no url. If you check the `session.driver.browser.client` you can see the client info is reset.

Comment: thanks! `session.driver.browser.restart` really woks